# How to find out all the initial coloring so that there is only one color on the chessboard after several operations？

Tags: combinatorics

> There is an  $n\times n$ checkerboard where each square is either white or black. You are allowed to perform the following operation as often as you like: select a square, and change its color, together with the colors of its neighboring squares (sharing an edge). Find all possible initial colorings, so that it is possible to make all squares the same color using this operation.

By chance, I saw this problem in **tieba** (a chinese BBS),no one have solved it till today.

Comment: "change the color between the $1∗1$ square and the $1∗1$ square with adjacent sides" is not clear to me.  Are you changing one square at a time or up to five as in the game [Flip](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/flip.html)?

Comment: @Henry like the flip,sir.